# Wookmark plugin on fixed position with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the code I have

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/KUYeJ/3/

Here is what I am trying to do (requirements):

- `.left` has known fixed width of `100px`
- `.right` must be `position:fixed` because I want it to stay still regardless of the `left` content. It will have a bunch of images in Pinterest style using Wookmark
  http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin
- `.right` needs to scroll independently using some scrollbar plugin. **I tried all below and none works: no scrollbar**.

http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

https://github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS

https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll

I was thinking it's because the usage of `position:fixed` causing it to not have overflow scroll. But I tried to adjust it in css and it still doesn't show scroll.

I am stuck at this point and would like to find out how to fix this. The following are **negotiable in term of requirements**.

- If I have to set a dynamic width in `.right`, that is OK. I think I can use jQuery to detect a change in window size. Because right now, it is expanding all the way as `right:0`
- If both `.left` and `.right` have to use the **artificial scrollbar**, that's OK too. Although ideally the `.left` one has browser default scrollbar (just like Facebook today: imagine the `.left` is Facebook Feed and `.right` is the Chat Panel)
- If I need to add more parent elements, I am OK too.

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: maybe this one help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166870/jquery-wookmark-plugin-infinite-load-scoll

Comment: That is a separate question though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using **slimScroll** but the trick is to change the html structure and where to apply the plugin.

This is the structure:

```
.scrollable
  .photo-thumbs
    %ul
      %li
```

Here is how to apply the plugin:

```
$('.scrollable').slimScroll();
$('.photo-thumbs ul li').wookmark();
```